# Terraform Removes Configurations/Resources Created by the Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC)

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I have some Terraform code which deploys AKS behind an Application Gateway along with other infrastructure unrelated to the issue. The code is based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-k8s-cluster-with-aks-applicationgateway-ingress. I can provide the actual files if needed.

All the infrastructure is being deployed successfully on initial creation, however when I configure the AGIC pods and deploy an application such as Nginx, it creates resources such as routing rules on the Application Gateway that is unknown to Terraform so if I run a Terraform deployment, it will revert back to what is in code (regardless if I made any changes or not). This causes the routing to my application through the ingress controller to return a 502 until it is redeployed.

How can I work around this?

```
> terraform apply -var-file=".\env\DEV.tfvars"
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
azurerm_resource_group.k8snetworkingrg: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG]
azurerm_resource_group.k8srg: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sRG]
azurerm_resource_group.acrrg: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sCRRG]
azurerm_resource_group.k8ssupportrg: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sSupportRG]
azurerm_container_registry.acr: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sCRRG/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/DEVK8sCR]
azurerm_public_ip.publicip: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/DEV-K8sPublicIP]
azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DEV-K8sVNET]
azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourcegroups/DEV-k8ssupportrg/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/DEV-k8sloganalyticsworkspace]
data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnet1: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DEV-K8sVNET/subnets/DevTestSubnet1]
azurerm_virtual_network_peering.vnet_peer: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DEV-K8sVNET/virtualNetworkPeerings/DevTest-K8stoDevTest-Peering]
data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnet_ag: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DEV-K8sVNET/subnets/DevTestAppGatewaySubnet]
azurerm_application_gateway.appgateway: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway]
azurerm_log_analytics_solution.log: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourcegroups/DEV-K8sSupportRG/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/Containers(DEV-K8sLogAnalyticsWorkspace)]
azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourcegroups/DEV-K8sRG/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/DEV-K8sAKS]
azurerm_role_assignment.aks_sp_container_registry: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sCRRG/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/DEVK8sCR/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/b8cd7474-fd5a-b4b0-3715-0c15e368c4fc]
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
Terraform will perform the following actions:
  # azurerm_application_gateway.appgateway will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "appgateway" {
        enable_http2        = false
        id                  = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway"
        location            = "northcentralus"
        name                = "DEV-K8sAppGateway"
        resource_group_name = "DEV-K8sNetworkingRG"
      ~ tags                = {
            "Application"                 = "Kubernetes"
            "Environment"                 = "DevTest"
            "Owner"                       = "IT"
          - "ingress-for-aks-cluster-id"  = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourcegroups/DEV-k8srg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/DEV-k8saks" -> null
          - "last-updated-by-k8s-ingress" = "2020-08-28 16:38:26.637125695 +0000 UTC m=+67.233012328" -> null
          - "managed-by-k8s-ingress"      = "1.2.0/32ea3149/2020-06-25-20:09T+0000" -> null
        }
        zones               = []
      ~ backend_address_pool {
            fqdns        = []
            id           = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/backendAddressPools/defaultaddresspool"
            ip_addresses = []
          ~ name         = "defaultaddresspool" -> "DEV-K8sBackendAddressPool"
        }
      - backend_address_pool {
          - fqdns        = [] -> null
          - id           = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/backendAddressPools/pool-default-nginx-80-bp-80" -> null
          - ip_addresses = [
              - "10.11.0.23",
            ] -> null
          - name         = "pool-default-nginx-80-bp-80" -> null
        }
      ~ backend_http_settings {
            cookie_based_affinity               = "Disabled"
            id                                  = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/backendHttpSettingsCollection/bp-default-nginx-80-80-nginx"
          ~ name                                = "bp-default-nginx-80-80-nginx" -> "DEV-K8sBackendHTTPSetting"
            pick_host_name_from_backend_address = false
            port                                = 80
            probe_id                            = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/probes/pb-default-nginx-80-nginx"
          - probe_name                          = "pb-default-nginx-80-nginx" -> null
            protocol                            = "Http"
          ~ request_timeout                     = 30 -> 1
            trusted_root_certificate_names      = []
        }
      - backend_http_settings {
          - cookie_based_affinity               = "Disabled" -> null
          - id                                  = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/backendHttpSettingsCollection/defaulthttpsetting" -> null
          - name                                = "defaulthttpsetting" -> null
          - pick_host_name_from_backend_address = false -> null
          - port                                = 80 -> null
          - probe_id                            = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/probes/defaultprobe-Http" -> null
          - probe_name                          = "defaultprobe-Http" -> null
          - protocol                            = "Http" -> null
          - request_timeout                     = 30 -> null
          - trusted_root_certificate_names      = [] -> null
        }
        frontend_ip_configuration {
            id                            = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/frontendIPConfigurations/DEV-K8sFrontendIPConfig"
            name                          = "DEV-K8sFrontendIPConfig"
            private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
            public_ip_address_id          = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/DEV-K8sPublicIP"
        }
        frontend_port {
            id   = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/frontendPorts/httpPort"
            name = "httpPort"
            port = 80
        }
      + frontend_port {
          + id   = (known after apply)
          + name = "httpsPort"
          + port = 443
        }
        gateway_ip_configuration {
            id        = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/gatewayIPConfigurations/DEV-K8sAppGatewayIpConfig"
            name      = "DEV-K8sAppGatewayIpConfig"
            subnet_id = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/DEV-K8sVNET/subnets/DevTestAppGatewaySubnet"
        }
      ~ http_listener {
            frontend_ip_configuration_id   = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/frontendIPConfigurations/DEV-K8sFrontendIPConfig"
            frontend_ip_configuration_name = "DEV-K8sFrontendIPConfig"
            frontend_port_id               = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/frontendPorts/httpPort"
            frontend_port_name             = "httpPort"
            host_names                     = []
            id                             = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/httpListeners/fl-e1903c8aa3446b7b3207aec6d6ecba8a"
          ~ name                           = "fl-e1903c8aa3446b7b3207aec6d6ecba8a" -> "DEV-K8sListenerHTTP"
            protocol                       = "Http"
            require_sni                    = false
        }
      - probe {
          - host                                      = "localhost" -> null
          - id                                        = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/probes/defaultprobe-Http" -> null
          - interval                                  = 30 -> null
          - minimum_servers                           = 0 -> null
          - name                                      = "defaultprobe-Http" -> null
          - path                                      = "/" -> null
          - pick_host_name_from_backend_http_settings = false -> null
          - protocol                                  = "Http" -> null
          - timeout                                   = 30 -> null
          - unhealthy_threshold                       = 3 -> null
          - match {
              - status_code = [] -> null
            }
        }
      - probe {
          - host                                      = "localhost" -> null
          - id                                        = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/probes/defaultprobe-Https" -> null
          - interval                                  = 30 -> null
          - minimum_servers                           = 0 -> null
          - name                                      = "defaultprobe-Https" -> null
          - path                                      = "/" -> null
          - pick_host_name_from_backend_http_settings = false -> null
          - protocol                                  = "Https" -> null
          - timeout                                   = 30 -> null
          - unhealthy_threshold                       = 3 -> null
          - match {
              - status_code = [] -> null
            }
        }
      - probe {
          - host                                      = "localhost" -> null
          - id                                        = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/probes/pb-default-nginx-80-nginx" -> null
          - interval                                  = 30 -> null
          - minimum_servers                           = 0 -> null
          - name                                      = "pb-default-nginx-80-nginx" -> null
          - path                                      = "/" -> null
          - pick_host_name_from_backend_http_settings = false -> null
          - protocol                                  = "Http" -> null
          - timeout                                   = 30 -> null
          - unhealthy_threshold                       = 3 -> null
          - match {
              - status_code = [] -> null
            }
        }
      - request_routing_rule {
          - backend_address_pool_id    = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/backendAddressPools/pool-default-nginx-80-bp-80" -> null
          - backend_address_pool_name  = "pool-default-nginx-80-bp-80" -> null
          - backend_http_settings_id   = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/backendHttpSettingsCollection/bp-default-nginx-80-80-nginx" -> null
          - backend_http_settings_name = "bp-default-nginx-80-80-nginx" -> null
          - http_listener_id           = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/httpListeners/fl-e1903c8aa3446b7b3207aec6d6ecba8a" -> null
          - http_listener_name         = "fl-e1903c8aa3446b7b3207aec6d6ecba8a" -> null
          - id                         = "/subscriptions/<Subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/DEV-K8sNetworkingRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/DEV-K8sAppGateway/requestRoutingRules/rr-e1903c8aa3446b7b3207aec6d6ecba8a" -> null
          - name                       = "rr-e1903c8aa3446b7b3207aec6d6ecba8a" -> null
          - rule_type                  = "Basic" -> null
        }
      + request_routing_rule {
          + backend_address_pool_id    = (known after apply)
          + backend_address_pool_name  = "DEV-K8sBackendAddressPool"
          + backend_http_settings_id   = (known after apply)
          + backend_http_settings_name = "DEV-K8sBackendHTTPSetting"
          + http_listener_id           = (known after apply)
          + http_listener_name         = "DEV-K8sListenerHTTP"
          + id                         = (known after apply)
          + name                       = "DEV-K8sRequestRoutingRuleHTTP"
          + redirect_configuration_id  = (known after apply)
          + rewrite_rule_set_id        = (known after apply)
          + rule_type                  = "Basic"
          + url_path_map_id            = (known after apply)
        }
        sku {
            capacity = 1
            name     = "WAF_v2"
            tier     = "WAF_v2"
        }
        ssl_policy {
            cipher_suites      = []
            disabled_protocols = []
            policy_name        = "AppGwSslPolicy20150501"
            policy_type        = "Predefined"
        }
    }
Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.
  Enter a value:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not the approach I want, but looks like the one I will need. Basically you can configure Terraform to `ignore_changes` which will create all resources but ignore modifications. You can define the resources to ignore as well as you can see below:

```
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [
    backend_address_pool,
    backend_http_settings,
    frontend_port,
    http_listener,
    probe,
    redirect_configuration,
    request_routing_rule,
    ssl_certificate,
    tags,
    url_path_map,
  ]
}
```

This covers all the resources that are created/modified by the Azure AGIC pods.